# Installing openpyxl=2.4.1 version by using conda in spyder environment

Tags: python, excel, spyder, openpyxl, conda

I am using Spyder environment and IPython for data analysis. I am trying to read large excel files. Thus, I am trying to use openpyxl module and read_only mode. But, I couldn't upgrade version of openpyxl. To use read_only mode, I want to get 2.4.1 version of openpyxl module.
First, I typed `conda create -n openpyxl openpyxl` command to create an environment. Then I activated the environment by using `activate openpyxl` command. I activated python with `python <script.py>` command. I also install spyder into this environment by using `conda install spyder` command. When I typed this code, a spyder screen opens. However, when I tried to run the following code in this spyder screen

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('file.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
```

It gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

 File "<ipython-input-4-5c1badfdb387>", line 1, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

 File "openpyxl.py", line 8, in <module>
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
ImportError: cannot import name load_workbook
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you installed Spyder into this environment? Or did you install it to the root environment?

Comment: I activated the "openpyxl" environment then I wrote "conda install spyder". Thus I guess it should be installed into "openpyxl" environment. @darthbith

Comment: Did you open a new terminal after installing Spyder?

Comment: I did not. When I wrote "spyder", a Spyder screen opened and terminal closed.

Comment: OK, so if you open a new terminal and open spyder again, does the same error occur?

Comment: yes, exactly it does.